# Socket IO: How to send MB of data to clients while keeping server responsive

Tags: socket.io

I send data from 1 client to my server at 250ms interval using socket.emit

I would like to send this data (150kb) from my socket-io server to all clients in the room. It can be up to 30 clients and data can be up to some MB per second.

Seems my server cannot handle the amount of traffic very well and other emits from clients are not handled very well then. (lag).
Could i try to send it in chunks or just send it to 1 client and then listen to emits from clients again?

Question is how to unblock socket-io server when sending MB of data, so that it stays responsive.